# psexec.exe and remotely log off a Windows XP user

Tags: windows, windows-xp, shutdown, psexec, logoff

I have a Win7 SP1 system that I use to remotely log off some Win7 SP1 systems and some WinXP SP3 systems (yes, I know, I still have WinXP for some old systems with 512MB DDR RAM...)

I use the utility [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) with this command:

```
psexec \\laptopname -i -d shutdown -l -f
```

This works great for the Win7 systems, however for the WinXP systems it justs show an empty command prompt titled "C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe" that does not respond to the red "x".

All systems have the Windows Pro editions, all administrative shares are enabled and working and firewall is disabled.

Does anyone have a clue how to make it work for the WinXP systems?

Comment: The current version of PsExec (as linked) does not indicate that it supports Windows XP. Its minimum supported version is Windows Vista. Why not just use the `shutdown` command by itself? This supports shutting down remote systems.

Comment: Yes, it says that Vista or higher is supported, but every command I've used with `PsExec` for WinXP does work, except `psexec \\laptopname -i -d shutdown -l`. For example, `psexec \\laptopname -i -d shutdown -s` does work to shut it down. I cannot use the `shutdown` command by itself, because remote logoff is not supported (it says that I cannot use `-l` which is log off, together with `-m` which is remote computer).